# Using Curl to pull down Call Log Data

Tags: shell, api, curl, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I want to pull down call data from RingCentral using a shell script and curl.  I'm then going to put that into ELK to build a dashboard using Kibana.  However, I don't know what I'm doing with the API.  Does anyone have a place for me to start or some sample code to do this?

I'm currently struggling with just using curl to authenticate to get a token.  At the moment I keep getting unsupported grant type.  I setup the application in Sandbox and a "Server Only No UI".

I have run this from a Centos 7 box using a bash shell.

Here is the code have tried:

```
curl -X POST "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token"; \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-u "my client id:my client secret" \
-d "username=username&password=password&extension=<extension>&grant_type=password"
```

I left the username and password blank because I wasn't sure what that was.

The output is as follows:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Unsupported grant type",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "OAU-250",
    "message" : "Unsupported grant type"
  } ]
}./rctest1.sh: line 2: -H: command not found
```

Comment: Please provide some samples what you've tried so far.

Comment: We could use a bit more info, like what shell, what OS, and the code you have already tried, with the output log with your error messages.  And have you spelunked in the RingCentral GitHub repo:  https://github.com/ringcentral

Comment: I'm in the process of editing the original post.  I will also check out the github.com site per your post.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce your error and can resolve it by removing the semi-colon (`;`) after the URL in your command.

**Explanation**

A semi-colon creates two separate CLI commands instead of one, so in your call, you have two requests.

**- Your Request 1**

```
$ curl -X POST "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token"
```

**- Your Request 2**

```
$ -H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-u "my client id:my client secret" \
-d "username=username&password=password&extension=&grant_type=password"
```

**- Your Response 1**

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Unsupported grant type",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "OAU-250",
    "message" : "Unsupported grant type"
  } ]
}
```

**- Your Response 2**

```
./rctest1.sh: line 2: -H: command not found
```

**- Test Command**

Here's a simple test showing the OS trying to process two commands:

```
$ hello;world
-bash: hello: command not found
-bash: world: command not found
```

**Solution**

**- Working Request**

Here is a working request without the semi-colon:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-u "my client id:my client secret" \
-d "username=username&password=password&extension=&grant_type=password"
```

**- Working Response**

Here is the working response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "myAccessToken",
  "token_type" : "bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "myRefreshToken",
  "refresh_token_expires_in" : 604800,
  "scope" : "Meetings VoipCalling Glip SubscriptionWebhook Faxes Contacts RingOut SMS",
  "owner_id" : "11111111",
  "endpoint_id" : "22222222"
}
```